# Select a specific attribute based on the attributes value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I have a XML file in this format:

```
 <league country="argentina" name="Argentina: Torneo Federal A - Winners Stage" cup="False" id="2909" sub_id="29094">
  <match alternate_id="4187269" alternate_id_2="4394549" date="14.08.2015" id="4304775" static_id="14081523515562337775" status="FT" time="18:00">
    <home goals="2" id="2351556" name="Club Atletico Mitre"></home>
    <away goals="1" id="2337775" name="Chaco For Ever"></away>
    <events>
    <event assist="" assistid="" id="22958994" minute="32" player="Juan Pablo Villafane" playerid="" result="[1 - 0]" team="home" type="goal"></event>
    <event assist="" assistid="" id="22958995" minute="48" player="Aldo Visconti" playerid="" result="[1 - 1]" team="away" type="goal"></event>
    <event assist="" assistid="" id="22958996" minute="90" player="Emanuel Lazzarini" playerid="" result="[2 - 1]" team="home" type="goal"></event>
    </events>
    <ht score="[1-0]"></ht>
    <ft score="[2-1]"></ft>
    </match></league><league country="argentina" name="Argentina: Torneo Federal A - Losers Stage" cup="False" id="2909" sub_id="29095"><match alternate_id="4178253" alternate_id_2="4410516" date="14.08.2015" id="4295774" static_id="14081523557572337894" status="FT" time="18:00">
    <home goals="2" id="2355757" name="Velez de San Ramon"></home>
    <away goals="1" id="2337894" name="Sportivo Patria"></away>
    <events>
    <event assist="" assistid="" id="23118664" minute="11" player="Diego Suarez" playerid="" result="[1 - 0]" team="home" type="goal"></event>
    <event assist="" assistid="" id="23118665" minute="64" player="Luis Leguizamon" playerid="" result="[2 - 0]" team="home" type="goal"></event>
    <event assist="" assistid="" id="23118666" minute="67" player="Rodrigo Ramirez (o.g.)" playerid="" result="[2 - 1]" team="away" type="goal"></event>
    </events>
    <ht score="[1-0]"></ht>
    <ft score="[2-1]"></ft>
```

This is my controller:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML(f) 

  path = "//match[@static_id='user.matchid']"
  @country = xml.xpath(path)
```

How can I get the name of team, based on the condition that value of attribute `"result" = [1-0]` or `[0-1]`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you supply data or code, reduce it to the bare minimum necessary to show the problem you're having. In other words, your XML is extremely verbose and needs to be reduced. It's also invalid. While Nokogiri _can_ fix it up, doing so results in XML that often doesn't accurately reflect the original. Failing to provide accurate input data that reflects the true information slows or stops our ability to help you, so help us help you and provide accurate, minimal, data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
  <xml>
     <league>
      <match>
        <events>
          <event player="Juan Pablo Villafane" result="[1 - 0]" team="home"></event>
          <event player="Aldo Visconti" result="[1 - 1]" team="away"></event>
        </events>
        <events>
          <event player="Diego Suarez" result="[1 - 0]" team="home"></event>
          <event player="Luis Leguizamon" result="[2 - 0]" team="home"></event>
        </events>
      </match>
    </league>
  </xml>
EOT

doc.search('//event[contains(@result, "[1 - 0]") or contains(@result, "[0 - 1]")]/@team').map(&:text)
# => ["home", "home"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't stated clearly what is the condition to check *exactly*. So, here is an example condition for context, suppose you want to get name of home team of a match where final time score is `"[2-1]"` :

```
//match[ft/@score = '[2-1]']/home/@name
```